# there is performance hit or some other negative factor when using 'preg_replace' and array with several indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, preg-replace

there is performance hit or some other negative factor when using 'preg_replace' and array with several indexes?

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
...
$patterns[100] = '/fox/';

$replacements[0] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
...
$replacements[100] = 'slow';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well let's see

```
/** Get current time with microseconds */
function gettime() {
  list($ms, $s) = explode(' ', microtime());
  return (float)$s + (float)$ms;
}

define('PAT_COUNT', 20000);

$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();
// The string will be the same for both tests
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < PAT_COUNT; $i++) {
  $string .= "$i ";
  $patterns[] = "/$i /";
  $replacements[] = ":$i:";
}

$start = gettime();
$result1 = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
echo "preg_replace with arrays: ".(gettime() - $start)."\n";

$start = gettime();
$result2 = $string;
for($i = 0; $i < PAT_COUNT; $i++) {
  $result2 = preg_replace("/$i /", ":$i:", $result2);
}
echo "preg_replace inside of a loop: ".(gettime() - $start)."\n";
```

And output is

```
preg_replace with arrays: 19.568552017212
preg_replace inside of a loop: 20.119801044464
```

Actually it's even a bit faster, but not noteably. Maybe because it has some sort of optimized loop in it's implementation.

But who knows, maybe with your data the result will be different. Try making such a benchmark with samples of your data.

Answer (score 0):

For such easy lookups I recommend str_replace over regulare expression. It's also better to unroll a loop or use a Duff device when you want to compare a loop.